# Interaction with a GUI of minimized or hidden program

Tags: c#, user-interface, vb6, installation, element

I am making an installer that has multiple packages, some of those packages support silent install and some DON'T! 
Those that don't support silent install need user to click the buttons in order to install the package.
I am trying to find a way to pres and tick the GUI elements while the window is hidden from the user and get the fields back from the hidden or minimized GUI like License agreement and untick things like IE toolbars.

This is my development environment:
Windows 7 x64
Advanced Installer 10.0
Visual Basic 6
Visual Studio 2012

Thanks in advance!

Update: AutoIT and Koda do the trick for me! Thanks!

Comment: Usually when somebody publishes software and doesn't provide a redist package there are good odds there are restrictions on redistribution.  If there's a license agreement to accept there isn't much doubt left.  So what you are asking for help with is piracy at worst and wrong at best.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to look into Win32 API calls.

`FindWindowEx`, `PostMessage`, etc..

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/172wfck9.aspx